# In $\triangle ABC$ with $\angle A\;>\;\angle B\;>\;\angle C\;>\;\frac12 \angle A$, find the range for $\angle C$

Tags: triangles

> In $\triangle ABC$, $$\angle A\;>\;\angle B\;>\;\angle C\;>\;\frac12 \angle A$$
> Find the range for $\angle C$.

By

$$180^\circ=\angle A+\angle B+\angle C\;>\;\angle C+\angle C+\angle C\;=\;3\angle C$$

We can find the upper bound:
$$\angle C\;<\;60^\circ$$

But how shall we find the lower bound?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well ,   $90^\circ=\frac{180^\circ}{2}=\frac{A}{2}+\frac{B}{2}+\frac{C}{2}\le C+C+\frac{C}{2}=\frac{5C}{2}$
$\Rightarrow C \ge \frac{90^\circ * 2}{5}=$ $\textbf{36}$ $^\circ$

Why is $\frac{A}{2}+\frac{B}{2}+\frac{C}{2}\le C+C+\frac{C}{2}$ ?

$\textbf{Answer :}$   $\frac{A}{2}\le C$  and $B\le A \Rightarrow \frac{B}{2} \le \frac{A}{2} \le C$

So , adding them up and adding $\frac{C}{2}$ on both sides  , we get

$\frac{A}{2}+\frac{B}{2}+\frac{C}{2}\le C+C+\frac{C}{2}$